# uninitialized constant Valium::ValueOf (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I got error when i start rails project as the following error. I feel it may be because of incompatible gem version but i am not sure if it is because of Bundler gem or Valium gem. Thank in advance for the reply.

```
root@ip-10-152-178-228:/var/www/resource_map_sea# bundle exec rails s
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/valium-0.5.0/lib/valium.rb:113:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Valium::ValueOf (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /var/www/resource_map_sea/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@resource_map_v4/gems/railties-4.1.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It seems like the issue is coming from the Valium gem itself as you can see in the path in the backtrace. Perhaps try changing the version to the latest working version in your Gemfile?

Comment: Thank @DavidMeza. I already install the latest valium gem but it come up with error. I figured out that it is because bundler problem. It work when bundler gem version is 1.9.1 while 1.5.3 is not working.

Comment: Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) this code in the production configuration file come with error. that's why i feel may be bundler could kill my app.